# How to edit/reset Chrome DevTools settings manually on disk?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, settings, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome 44 there is a new DevTools experiment called "Material design" (you have to enable DevTools experiments and then do the 6 <kbd>shift</kbd> presses).

After enabling that experiment, DevTools does not open anymore. I tried different ways of starting it (including `chrome://inspect`) but to no avail.
It actually does open as I can see the DevTools URL in `chrome://inspect/#other`
[image]

But the panel does not show up.

So I have no way to disable that particular experiments through the UI.
What I *can* do is to disable all DevTools experiments with `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments`, and after that DevTools works normally again. But then I have no way to enable the other experiments that I do want.

Is there a way to manually edit DevTools settings in some file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some quick steps that should work:

1. Disable experiments and open DevTools.
2. Pop DevTools out into its own window (long press the dock to bottom button and select pop out.)
3. With the DevTools window focused, inspect it (Ctrl + Shift +I).
4. Go to resources > localstorage. Then to `chrome-devtools://devtools`
5. Delete the experiments key.
6. Re-enable experiments.

Comment: Awesome. Just what I needed. I just removed the "materialDedign" key from the json string and it worked.

Comment: @GetFree If you accepted an answer which helps you but doesn't really answer the original question, please rename the title so that it wouldn't misinform those looking for a real answer.

Comment: Now I'm not sure had my reply any sense or not, becuse it's not clear can you edit title afterwards.

Comment: Instead of just asserting it isn't answering the question, explain why you feel that way. The question was, how to turn off experiments when you can't get to the experimental settings. That is exactly what was answered.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open dev tools with Ctrl + Shift + I.
2. Click Customize icon (three dots) on upper right.
3. Click Settings.
4. Click 'Restore defaults and reload' button on lower right corner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset all devtools settings, you can also remove `Local Storage/chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage*` from your Google Chrome profile directory and restart Chrome.

If you want to reset just the experiments settings and have sqlite3 client handy, you can open up `Local Storage/chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage` and remove the setting:

```
delete from ItemTable where key = 'experiments';
```

… and of course restart Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 79 on Linux systems the preferences file is located at:

`~/.config/google-chrome/<Profile name>/Preferences`

For the default profile the path would be:

`~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`

**Why would you want to edit that file?**

For instance, if you enter a wrong regexp in the Console's text filter field, you will most likely find DevTools not functioning at all (Check out this topic for an illustration: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/26946315?hl=en). The only workaround I found so far was editing that file directly. I manually deleted the value of the entry:

`devtools > preferences > console.textFilter`

Note that the file may be really huge, so you should use some mighty editor which can handle big JSONs or just edit it as a regular text file.